# How to run provision.sh on vagrant with docker provider

Tags: vagrant, docker

I have used vagrant successfully on many clouds now.

I have decided to try something with docker, but I am probably missing something very basic as I am failing tremendously.

I wrote this vagrant file:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder "../synced_folder", "/vagrant"

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "provision.sh"
    s.privileged = false
  end

  config.vm.provider :docker do |docker, override|
    docker.image = 'ubuntu'

  end
end
```

this configuration worked for me for other clouds (if I add specific cloud details to it of course).

my `provision.sh` file simply has `echo "hello world"`

my synced_folder has a dummy file..

I have verified that `ubuntu` image is working fine in docker. docker seems to be working fine.

When I run `vagrant up --provider docker` I get the following

```
The container started either never left the "stopped" state or
very quickly reverted to the "stopped" state. This is usually
because the container didn't execute a command that kept it running,
and usually indicates a misconfiguration.

If you meant for this container to not remain running, please
set the Docker provider configuration "remains_running" to "false":

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.remains_running = false
  end
```

I do not see the `hello world` print out.

I have found a lot of Q&A regarding this error, but nothing I could use to resolve my problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have been missing something very fundamental.

The solution I found is easy. Use this amazing contribution from:

https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example

The important thing to note here is the Dockerfile - which defines the SSH connection in the container. Without the SSH it simply won't work.

However - another tacit fact people are missing - docker uses a socket which requires permissions, however runnign `sudo vagrant up --provider` will not resolve the issue. in order to run without problems you should `sudo su -` first OR add your user to `docker` group.

Read more about that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

So to summarize:

- clone the git repository
- sudo su -
- vagrant up --provider docker

==> machine is up and running perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

Been experiencing the same and following https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3951 for a while. Looks like this is to be fixed by the upcoming minor release of Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

```
config.vm.provider :docker do |docker, override|
    docker.image = 'ubuntu'

end
```

You are missing a command here, you need a command to run the container. something like this:

```
config.vm.provider :docker do |docker, override|
    docker.image = 'ubuntu'
    docker.run = 'ubuntu'
end
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
config.vm.provider :docker do |docker, override|
    docker.image = 'ubuntu'
    docker.cmd = ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
end
```

Comment: even though this will run the command I am looking for running the provision script. seems the answer to this is to set up the SSH.

Comment: If there's only simple things in the provision.sh, you can put them in the Dockerfile, they will be executed when you do a vagrant up. Another option: For SSH, you can either add a ssh service to the ubuntu base image [link](https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/), or pull an existing ssh enabled base image, such as phusion [link](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)